# How to bind Command-b to move back by a word in iTerm/ZSH?

Tags: zsh, iterm2

I just installed iTerm and have ZSH because I have Catalina.

I used to have Bash and Catalina instead, and an iTerm installation on a different laptop that I have gradually configured over the years.

So I can't remember the specific steps I took to get ⌘-b/⌘-f to work as backward-word/forward-word in Bash. And trying to search for a combination of possible keywords (binding, mapping, emacs mode, zsh, iterm, etc.) didn't yield an answer to this question.

I copied over the .inputrc from my previous machine but that hasn't helped.

What are the steps necessary here? Is it a combination of Zsh settings along with iTerm key binding settings?

Answer (score 1):

### iTerm

Go to Preferences -> Keys -> Key Bindings

1. Click the `+` to add a new key binding
2. Where the popup says "Click to Set" left click
3. Press `cmd+b`
4. Click the drop-down menu named "action" and select "Move Start of Selection Back"
5. Choose in the new drop down that appears underneath "Move by (Character|Word|Line|Mark)"
6. Press "Ok" close prefs.

You're done.

---

### zsh

Apparently (I just tried it)

- `esc+b` moves the cursor backwards.
- `esc+f` moves the cursor forwards.

Learn something new every day:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48675305/keybindings-with-zsh